# Expanding URL placeholders in Teams personal tab app seems to work incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm writing personal tab app for MS Teams. I have no problem to load initial page into the tab, but I'd like to get tenant id on this initial GET, so I thought about using URL placeholders mentioned in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context?tabs=teamsjs-v2). As mentioned there, for TeamsJS 2.0.0 or later `{user.tenant.id}` placeholder should be used, while for earlier versions, correct placeholder is `{tid}`.

My manifest version is 1.15, which supports TeamsJS 2.0.0 or later, but during my tests `{tid}` is expanded, while `{user.tenant.id}` is not. My tab's contentUrl is:

`https://teams.test.dev/Home/Debug?tenant1={tid}&tenant2={user.tenant.id}`

which is sent by Teams as:

`https://teams.test.dev/Home/Debug?tenant1=ACTUAL-TENANT-GUID&tenant2=%7buser.tenant.id%7d`

while I'd expect:

`https://teams.test.dev/Home/Debug?tenant1=%7btid%7d&tenant2=ACTUAL-TENANT-GUID`

Is there an error in the above documentation, or is there something that I missed?

My manifest (with GUIDs and domains replaced):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.15/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifestVersion": "1.15",
    "id": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
    "packageName": "dev.test.teams",
    "name": {
        "short": "Test Dev",
        "full": "Test development app"
    },
    "developer": {
        "name": "Dev",
        "mpnId": "",
        "websiteUrl": "https://teams.test.dev",
        "privacyUrl": "https://teams.test.dev/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://teams.test.dev/termsofuse"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Short description",
        "full": "This is a long description..."
    },
    "icons": {
        "outline": "outline.png",
        "color": "color.png"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "staticTabs": [
        {
            "entityId": "22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222",
            "name": "Debug",
            "contentUrl": "https://teams.test.dev/Home/Debug?tenant1={tid}&tenant2={user.tenant.id}",
            "websiteUrl": "https://teams.test.dev/Home/Debug",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        },
        {
            "entityId": "about",
            "scopes": [
                "personal"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "*.test.dev"
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333",
        "resource": "api://teams.test.dev/33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to hear Microsoft's answer on this (the team is very active on this site, fortunately), but it would seem to me that while your *code* can use TeamsJS v2, passing the correct querystring value would depend on the Teams client and is totally outside of your control. It might be that you need an updated client to get this to work, or it might be a bug in the *current* Teams client, but in any case, in your code you could just rely on `{tid}` for whatever comes in the querystring, and user.tenant.id once you've gotten the Teams context. This is probably reasonably future proof because I can't see Microsoft breaking the querystring name any time soon - it would be a major problem for existing customer and ISV code.

Comment: You're right that it's totally outside of my control. I thought on this earlier, because it doesn't matter whether I include specific teams JS script in my page or not, because initial GET doesn't have a chance to reach and execute anything from this file. I use recent Teams version (desktop), and whatever is served by browser, but I guess it is recent too :) In general, what I understand from the docs, version of manifest could somehow control the version of JS used internally by Teams client. But that's only a wild guess...

Comment: @ArekDygas- We are able to repro that issue, we have raised bug for the same and concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.

Comment: @ArekDygas - This is currently expected. The new style of placeholders still do not work in Teams.